# combining angular js and php - failed insert data into database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

its been two days since i start to learning about angular js.
its quite fun actually. fyi, im still using static data.

it means nothing when you cant manipulate database rite? 
so i jump into the next step. connect it with my db. im using regular php.
if success, i will jump into next step, combining angular and php framework like laravel or codeigniter.

actually, its quit easy to retrieve data from database.

but, im here not to share that story, i found difficulties when trying to input it into database. i dont understand why. the point is i cant get the data from the form in html. im using factory in angular.

here is my add.html :

```
<h1>add newdata</h1>
new name :
<input type='text' ng-model='newdata.name'> <br>
new city :
<input type='text' ng-model='newdata.city'> <br>

<button ng-click='addData()'>submit</button>
```

here is my index.html :

```
//define dependency ngRoute module
var test = angular.module('testPeople', ['ngRoute']);

test.factory('factoryPeople', function($http) {
    var factoryPeople= {};

    factoryPeople.getPeople = function() {
        return $http.get('data.php');
    };

    factoryPeople.addPeople = function() {
        return $http.post('add.php');
    };

    return factoryPeople;
});
```

routes :

```
test.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/add', {
        templateUrl : 'add.html',
        controller : 'add'
    })

    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'contact.html'
    })

    .when('/second', {
        templateUrl : 'index2.html'
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

controller :

```
test.controller('add', function($scope, $http, factoryPeople){
    $scope.tambahData = function() {

    //bikin format file json, dari hasil tangkapan form di file add.html
    databaru = {
        name: $scope.newdata.name,
        city: $scope.newdata.city
    }   

    factoryPeople.addPeople(newdata).success(function(result) {
        //update data using push method
        $scope.listofname.push({
            name: $scope.newdata.name,
            city: $scope.newdata.city
        });

        //set form data empty again
        $scope.newdata.name= '';
        $scope.newdata.city = '';

        alert(result);

    });
```

here is my add.php :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "angular";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die(mysqli_error($link));

// get input data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// take value from array
$name= $data['name'];
$city= $data['city'];

// query insert
$sql = "insert into users (name , city) values ('$name', '$city') ";

// echo message
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)):
    echo"input success| name: $name| city: $city";
else: echo"input failed| name : $name | city: $city";
endif;


?>
```

if i run that script, data will always succesfully insert into database.
but the problems is $name and $city has no value.

i dont understand why.
am i wrong using php_get_contents or what?
can you guys tell me what should i do in order to get a better result?

Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check developer console to see if the request was actually sending any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot  to pass the parameters. Change your factory (`addPeople()` function):

```
factoryPeople.addPeople = function(data) {
    return $http.post('add.php', data);
};
```

And then just use `$_POST` on the server like you usually (I guess) do

Comment: yeah i forgot to pass the parameters. thanks alot mate

Comment: yeah i forgot to pass the parameters. thanks alot mate. in php all i need to do is treat data like an object. using this : $name= $data->name;
$city= $data->city;